# How can i make this command run on a stored variable?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**I want to execute a command in my program by a value stored in a variable.**

at the moment it works like this:

you need to write the value in the command, so if I want to filter by 'Americas' region, I need to do this:

```
wine.loc[wine['Region'] == 'Americas']
```

but what I want is to have a code line somewhere else in the code like:

```
abc = 'Americas'
```

and that the loc line runs by what is stored in the abc variable

Comment: `wine.loc[wine['Region'] == abc]`?

Comment: ok thanks, and if I want to show all regions with no filter, what should be written on abc variable?

Comment: can you not do something like 
if( abc == "AllRegions"):
   return wine
else:
wine.loc[wine['Region'] == abc]  ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a seperate dataframe to be created for All regions, create a loop and store every dataframe in a dictionary of dataframes like below:

```
dfs = ['df' + str(x) for x in list(wine['Region'].unique())]
dicdf = dict()
i = 0 
while i < len(dfs):
    dicdf[dfs[i]] = wine[(wine['Region']==list(wine['Region'].unique())[i])]
    i = i + 1
print(dicdf)
```

This will print a dictionary of the dataframes. You can print what dataframe you like to see for example data for `'Americas'` : `print(dicdf['dfAmericas'])`

Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

check if the string is not empty and then filter

```
if abc:
    wine = wine.loc[wine['Region'] == abc]
```

if u want to filter multiple values u can use

```
abc = ['Americas','Europe']
wine  = wine.loc[wine['Region'].isin(abc)]
```